# Ontology applications and inference rules

Tags: ontology

actually my project is based on ontology(knowledge base). Here i created an ontology from which the data should be retrieved. An application where the question will be asked and the required answers will be retrieved from the ontology and print as output.
Here my doubt is how to construct the inference rules (i.e) how to convert the given keyword into queries? 
If anyone has any idea about construction inference rules and the language to be used for inference rules just reply......  Thanx........

Comment: Yikes, pretty soon we'll be asked to write Doctoral Thesis'

Answer (score 3):

I'll define the major points that I've used in the past to explore this vast topic (ontology/web semantic/rdf/etc...):

- First you should define your ontology and rules set using some ontology editor (I've used [Protégé](http://protege.stanford.edu/)). This tool gives the opportunity to you create instances and test your ontology (it you check the inference rules)

After that if you want to store your data you need sesame server and some scripts to insert data into sesame.

- Sesame has the capability to store the triples information ([Sesame](http://www.openrdf.org/about.jsp)) - there is OpenRDF Workbench that acts as a administration console for sesame (good tool)
- After that I've used python and some libraries ([SuRF](http://packages.python.org/SuRF/), rdflib) to gather information from the web (querying data using SPARQL - I've used the dblp sparql endpoint) and inserting that data (triples) into my sesame server

To make queries you will need to learn SPARQL :) give it a try --> http://dblp.rkbexplorer.com/sparql/

Good luck!